# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm a beginner in everything programming and have been trying to implement some self learned stuff from the Big Nerd Ranch Books. But I'm really stumped by this problem, and yes, I have searched this and other forums for possible solutions with no success. Here is the code:

ANKYViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ANKYViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *weightFieldDeadlift;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *repFieldDeadlift;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *workingOneRMDeadlift;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *weightFieldBenchPress;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *repFieldBenchPress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *workingOneRMBenchPress;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *weightFieldSquat;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *repFieldSquat;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *workingOneRMSquat;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *weightFieldMilitaryPress;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *repFieldMilitaryPress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *workingOneRMMilitaryPress;

- (IBAction)calculateOneRM:(id)sender;

@end
```

ANKYViewController.m:

```
#import "ANKYViewController.h"

@interface ANKYViewController ()

@end

@implementation ANKYViewController
@synthesize weightFieldDeadlift;
@synthesize repFieldBenchPress;
@synthesize workingOneRMBenchPress;
@synthesize weightFieldSquat;
@synthesize repFieldSquat;
@synthesize workingOneRMSquat;
@synthesize weightFieldMilitaryPress;
@synthesize repFieldMilitaryPress;
@synthesize workingOneRMMilitaryPress;
@synthesize repFieldDeadlift;
@synthesize workingOneRMDeadlift;
@synthesize weightFieldBenchPress;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setWeightFieldDeadlift:nil];
    [self setRepFieldDeadlift:nil];
    [self setWorkingOneRMDeadlift:nil];
    [self setWeightFieldDeadlift:nil];
    [self setRepFieldBenchPress:nil];
    [self setWeightFieldBenchPress:nil];
    [self setWorkingOneRMBenchPress:nil];
    [self setWeightFieldSquat:nil];
    [self setRepFieldSquat:nil];
    [self setWorkingOneRMSquat:nil];
    [self setWeightFieldMilitaryPress:nil];
    [self setRepFieldMilitaryPress:nil];
    [self setWorkingOneRMMilitaryPress:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)calculateOneRM:(id)sender {
    float dw = [[weightFieldDeadlift text]floatValue];
    float dr = [[repFieldDeadlift text]floatValue];
    float d = (dw * dr * 0.0333) + dw;
    NSLog(@"Deadlift: %f", d);
    NSString *deadlift = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", d];
    [workingOneRMDeadlift setText:deadlift];

    float bpw = [[weightFieldBenchPress text]floatValue];
    float bpr = [[repFieldBenchPress text]floatValue];
    float bp = (bpw * bpr * 0.0333) + bpw;
    NSLog(@"Bench Press: %f", bp);
    NSString *benchPress = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", bp];
    [workingOneRMBenchPress setText:benchPress];

    float sw = [[weightFieldSquat text]floatValue];
    float sr = [[repFieldSquat text]floatValue];
    float s = (sw * sr * 0.0333) + sw;
    NSLog(@"Squat: %f", s);
    NSString *squat = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", s];
    [workingOneRMSquat setText:squat];

    float mpw = [[weightFieldMilitaryPress text]floatValue];
    float mpr = [[repFieldMilitaryPress text]floatValue];
    float mp = (mpw * mpr * 0.0333) + mpw;
    NSLog(@"Military Press: %f", mp);
    NSString *militaryPress = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", mp];
    [workingOneRMMilitaryPress setText:militaryPress];
}
@end
```

File's owner class is already stated as ANKYViewController. Linking the outlets etc was by control dragging instead of manually coding (I gave up after spending too many hours).

The error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x6c22e70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key repsField.'
```

There's no copy and pasting of code, and it's certainly distressing that there is no mentioning of "repsField"(instead of repFieldxxx) anywhere.

I hope that this is enough information to help lead to a solution, as I've spent days looking through other people's solutions with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in your NIB/XIB file too; it's possible for references to properties to be there (e.g. in a binding) even if they aren't in your code.

Comment: Note that the message says that `UIApplication` (not `ANKYViewController `) is not KVC compliant for `repsField`.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166470/showing-a-uiview-subclass-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the/11167245#11167245) for a general discussion of these errors.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the problem is that someone is accessing the `UIApplication` instance with a key (`repsField`) that is not KVC compliant.

**Update** I don't think you even need to subclass to add a breakpoint. Go to the breakpoint navigator and add a symbolic breakpoint for symbol `-[UIApplication setValue:forUndefinedKey:]` and then run the application.

I think you can debug it by subclassing `UIApplication` and set a breakpoint in a dummy override of the `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` method.

In the file where you call `UIApplicationMain` add this class:

```
@interface TestApplication : UIApplication
@end
@implementation TestApplication
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    [super setValue:value forUndefinedKey:key]; // set breakpoint here
}
@end
```

And then change the third argument to `UIApplicationMain` to `@"TestApplication"`, for example:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"TestApplication", NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Now run the application and it should break into to debugger and you should be able to see the call stack causing it.

Answer (score 1):

When this error message appears it is very often a bad connection in a xib file or storyboard.  I'll guess that this is an old example that has a MainWindow.xib file in it, with the File's Owner set as the UIApplication class.  There is most likely a connection in that xib to an outlet called `repsField` in the File's Owner which, of course, does not match anything in the actual class.