# iOS MediaPlayer makes application crash

Tags: ios, media-player

If I start with the very minimalist UI implementation consisting of adding a single UIButton (with the corresponding IBOutlet) to the default view in the default storyboard and adding an action method to my controller class, then everything works correctly (i.e. my action gets invoked when I tap the button).

Now, if I simply include MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h to my view controller header file, like that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface Playing_Video_FilesViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;

@end
```

and add the MediaPlayer framework to the project, it crashes with the infamous "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key playButton".

If I remove the MediaPlayer framework reference from the project, it stops to crash. If I instead remove the button but leave the MediaPlayer framework, it stops to crash as well.

Is there something else I should do to use MediaPlayer and a basic standard UI at the same time?

**Edit:**
I circumvented the problem by creating a .xib file instead of using the storyboard, like how it's done in the VideoPlayer sample application which doesn't use storyboards. Same code, but now it works.

Comment: have you synthesized the properties in your m file and made sure you have hooked up the IBOutlet of the playbutton correctly?

Comment: Yes I put the synthesize. I created the UIButton property by control-dragging from the UIButton in my storyboard to the view controller .h file. So it is certainly well hooked up. I am baffled.

Comment: You could go to the breakpoint navigator in xcode using the technique listed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275608/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxx

Answer (score 0):

I see this whenever I have an outlet or action that is no longer hooked up properly.

```
1.) Open storyboard
2.) Select playButton
3.) Remove all outlets and actions from this item
4.) Remove plugs from your class that were previously attached (especially in dealloc)
5.) Create new outlet and control-drag from the storyboard to your class. Good to go.
```

-A little overkill but gets the job done for me everytime.

Comment: That's what I did. There is something that it doesn't like with the MediaPlayer framework. Everything else works.